# Return true or false with preg match instead of echoing out a sentence

Tags: php, regex, foreach, preg-match

I am using the following to check to see if the data from a form contains certain words, the problem is though, when it checks I get "a match was found" or "a match was not found" over and over again a million times. How can I just assign a true or false value for the whole sentence that is posted ?. I want to then add something like....if true dump this post, if false process it and put it in the database.

```
    <?php
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    echo $message;

    $targets = array('viagra', 'prescription', 'drugs', 'zyban', 'zithromax', 'voltaren', 'cilias', 'FDA');

    foreach($targets as $t)
    {
        if (preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $message)) {
            echo "A match was found.";
        } else {
            echo "A match was not found.";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: `preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $message)` this itselfs return true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function containsSpam($message) {
    $targets = array('viagra', 'prescription', 'drugs', 'zyban', 'zithromax', 'voltaren', 'cilias', 'FDA');

    foreach($targets as $t)
    {
        if (preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $message)) {
            //A match was found.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im trying to check like this, but it keeps returning true ?.

$result = containsSpam($message);
if ($result = true){echo 'true';}else{echo 'false';}

Comment: You should use `==` for comparison and `=` for assignment. In the case of boolean value `if ($result)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right you need to set a stop value like this

```
<?php
function containsSpam($message) {
    $targets = array('viagra', 'prescription', 'drugs', 'zyban', 'zithromax', 'voltaren', 'cilias', 'FDA');        
    $stop = false;
    foreach($targets as $t)
    {
        if (preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $message)) {
            //A match was found.
            $stop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //And you can then do something like this
    if ($check) {
       //Insert it
    } else {
       //Dump it
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should add a `break;` to stop looping when a stop word has been found